# Coreplot CPTXYGraph plot not displaying correctly

Tags: swift, macos, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am using the latest version of Core Plot within a Swift program. The graph plots without a problem and shows the following[image]

If you look at the plot the lower portion of the gradient fill for the plot does not match the xAxis which is the behaviour that I expect.  instead it starts part way up the yAxis.

I have not experienced this behaviour before and am not sure where to hunt for the bug in my code.  I haven't been able to find a relevant entry elsewhere within stackOverflow or elsewhere on the net for that matter.

I have tested the plotspace variables and they are on the money, min/max for the Y axis is as expected and the X/Y coords through the delegate functions shown below [number()  and  numberOfRecords()] are as expected.  I am not sure what within core plot will be driving this behaviour.

If anyone is able to suggest other areas to examine for the error that would be greatly appreciated.

Rather than post all of the code initially, if someone can suggest an area to explore I will add that element of the code in to the question to help with the diagnosis.  I have initially only included the code for the section of the app that defines the scatter line plot [configureLineGraph()] below the delegate functions below.

```
    // Delegate functions for Core Plot
func numberOfRecords(for plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt {
    numberOfRecordsToBeDisplayedOnGraph = UInt(arrayOfCommanderProgress.count)
    return  numberOfRecordsToBeDisplayedOnGraph // this needs to represent the number of records to be displayed on the graph
}

func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field fieldEnum: UInt, record idx: UInt) -> Any? {
    let index = Int(numberOfRecordsToBeDisplayedOnGraph - idx) - 1
    switch CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(fieldEnum))! {
    case .X:
        let xCoord = (arrayOfCommanderProgress[index].timeStamp.convertDateStringToDateObject()).timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        return xCoord
    case .Y:
        var yCoord = Double()
        if fieldEnum == 1 {
            switch graphToDisplay {
            case graphCombat:
                yCoord = (Double(self.arrayOfCommanderProgress[index].combat)) + (100.0 * (Double(arrayOfRankProgress[index].combat)))
            case graphTrade:
                yCoord = (Double(self.arrayOfCommanderProgress[index].trade)) + (100.0 * (Double(arrayOfRankProgress[index].trade)))
            case graphExploration:
                yCoord = (Double(self.arrayOfCommanderProgress[index].explore)) + (100.0 * (Double(arrayOfRankProgress[index].explore)))
            case graphFederation:
                yCoord = (Double(self.arrayOfCommanderProgress[index].federation)) + (100.0 * (Double(arrayOfRankProgress[index].federation)))
            case graphEmpire:
                yCoord = (Double(self.arrayOfCommanderProgress[index].empire)) + (100.0 * (Double(arrayOfRankProgress[index].empire)))
            case graphCQC:
                yCoord = (Double(self.arrayOfCommanderProgress[index].cQC)) + (100.0 * (Double(arrayOfRankProgress[index].cQC)))
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        return yCoord
    }
}


 // Funtions to set up the graphView and plots
func configureLineGraph() {

    // Plotline variables for scatterplot
    let plotLineTotal = CPTScatterPlot()
    let areaGradient:CPTGradient = CPTGradient(beginning: CPTColor.clear(), ending: CPTColor(componentRed: 150/255.0, green: 180/255.0, blue: 200/255.0, alpha: 0.9))
    areaGradient.angle = 90.0
    let areaGradientFill:CPTFill = CPTFill(gradient: areaGradient)

    // Set up plot lines for each type of total to be graphed
    plotLineTotal.areaFill = areaGradientFill

    // set up plotline characteristics
    let plotLineType = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    plotLineType.lineColor = CPTColor.darkGray()

    // establish a reference to the graph custom view
    guard let graph = graphView.hostedGraph else { return }

    // Add additional plotlines to the plots Array if needed
    let plots = [plotLineTotal]
    for plot in plots {
        plot.dataSource = self
        plot.delegate = self
        plot.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) as NSNumber
        plot.dataLineStyle = plotLineType
        graph.add(plot, to: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
    }
    graph.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This looks like a data problem, e.g., the data points are shifted along the x-axis from where you expect. Double-check the time stamps and make sure they're in the order you expect. The data line is wrapping around, cutting off the fill underneath.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Eric.  I will explore the data issue today and report back.  If it is a data issue I will update the question accordingly as it may help others.

Comment: @ericskroch - that was indeed the problem.  Elsewhere in the code and had added items to the source database but had not re-ordered the database that was then used to create the plot.  Thanks for the comment again.  Understanding that the data line was wrapping round was the key to solving this.